# Por que minha imagem está passando da minha div?

Tags: html, css

Defini uma altura para minha div, com 300px de altura e largura, porém a imagem está saindo fora da minha div, porém quando eu utilizo o bootstrap em um cartão a imagem fica totalmente certa dentro da div por que isso acontece ?

Exemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste imagem</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        .conteudo{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://tecnoblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/tv-4k-tcl-c6-c6us-6.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="https://tecnoblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/tv-4k-tcl-c6-c6us-6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Pois a imagem esta sendo formatada para o mesmo tamanho da `div`, manualmente é só adicionar `height` e `width` na tag `<img>`, no seu caso `height = 300px`

Comment: Uma maneira de resolver isso é colocar as dimensões direto na tag da imagem: `<img width="300" height:"300" src="https://tecnoblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/tv-4k-tcl-c6-c6us-6.jpg">`

Comment: @RafaelPassos se fizer isso vai quebrar a proporcionalidade da imagem pois ele não é quadrada.

Comment: @PedroRoweder Mesmo problema do comentário acima.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste imagem</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        .conteudo{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://tecnoblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/tv-4k-tcl-c6-c6us-6.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="https://tecnoblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/tv-4k-tcl-c6-c6us-6.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

assim sua `div` terá um tamanho na qual a sua imagem irá pegar e se encaixar com 100% do tamanho dela

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que na imagem dentro do `Card` tem a classe `card-img-top`, e essa classe define a imagem com `width` de `100%`, isso significa que a imagem vai ficar com 100% da largura do elemento que ela está dentro.

Se vc colocar uma imagem com `100%` de `width` dentro de uma `div` com `300px`, essa imagem fica com `300px` de largura, mas se vc colocar uma imagem de `500px` dentro de uma `div` de `300px` a imagem vai estourar o tamanho da `div`, ela não vai respeitar a largura da `div`, por isso é comum declarar `width:100%` nas imagens, para que ele tenha no máximo a largura do elemento no qual está dentro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele se refere à primeira imagem e não a que está dentro do card. No caso a resposta do DbaAlone atende, porque faltou colocar a classe .conteudo na div.

Comment: @Sam o que eu tinha entendido era *" porém quando eu utilizo o bootstrap em um cartão a imagem fica totalmente certa dentro da div **por que isso acontece ?**"* acho que vc tb tinha olhado por esse ponto

Comment: Sim, mas depois reli novamente a pergunta e ficou evidente o que ele quis dizer, embora haja uma certa confusão na elaboração da pergunta.

Comment: @Sam ficou confuso sim, até pq no código ele não usa a classe .conteudo. Parece que ele estava testando e no meio de erros e acertos ele ficou na dúvida e colou o código que estava na tela no momento... vai saber...

Comment: Daqui a pouco ele vai dizer "_foi mal, esqueci de colocar a classe na div_"... veja só rs

Comment: @Sam hahaha, típico 

Comment: Acho que o problema é que está _saindo fora_, pois se estivesse _saindo pra dentro_ acho que resolveria rsrs 